# Excel highlight particular text in a sentence

Tags: microsoft-excel, highlighting

I'm trying to highlight a text in a sentence that matches with the word in the other column. Lets say that column  A (contains 'ball', 'can') of different row B (contains 'He kicks a ball', 'He can eat that'.) of different row.

I need only the word in the sentence of column B that matches the word defined in column A to be highlighted and not the whole sentence. Is it doable? And how is it done?

[image]

Comment: This can only be done with VBA, and even then it's not trivial. Do you want to pursue that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if it is that difficult, i will just do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself asking the same question, maybe it's still relevant for some others. How to execute the code in Excel:

1. Developer tools
2. Visual Basic
3. Insert Module
4. Paste the code in the Module window
5. Adjust

   - comp1 = column number of the source words
   - comp2 = column number of sentences with word to highlight
   - length = number of rows to compare
6. execute the code (F5)

Code:

```
Sub highlight()
Dim counter As Integer
Dim counter2 As Integer
Dim counter1 As Integer
Dim textmarker As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim start As Integer
Dim comp1 As Integer
Dim comp2 As Integer

start = 0
comp1 = 1
comp2 = 2
length = 3

For counter = 1 To length
    For counter2 = 1 To Len(Cells(counter, comp2))
        For counter1 = 1 To Len(Cells(counter, comp1))
            If Cells(counter, comp2).Characters(counter2 + counter1 - 1, 1).Text <> Cells(counter, comp1).Characters(counter1, 1).Text Then
                start = 0
                Exit For
            End If
            If Cells(counter, comp2).Characters(counter2 + counter1 - 1, 1).Text = Cells(counter, comp1).Characters(counter1, 1).Text And start = 0 Then
                start = counter2
                tempCouner = tempCounter + 1
            End If
            Next
            If start <> 0 Then
                For textmarker = start To start + Len(Cells(counter, comp1)) - 1
                Cells(counter, comp2).Characters(textmarker, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Next
            End If
            start = 0
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```